# Excel Index and Match function returns #Ref error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The following Excel function works well when dragging or coping the formula down a column but dragging OR copying across the sheet creates an error AND The formula analyzer (pictured in the snap shot) is OK for the formula below

```
=INDEX($L$7:$L$44,MATCH($A3,$I$7:$I$44,0),MATCH(B1,$J$7:$J$44,0),1)
```

BUT when changing B1 to C2 for the next column generates the error

```
=INDEX($L$7:$L$44,MATCH($A3,$I$7:$I$44,0),MATCH(C2,$J$7:$J$44,0))
```

and the evaluator changes the italicized number to 2

```
=INDEX($L$7:$L$44,1,2)
```

Seems to be selecting another table to MATCH the result to

[image]

Comment: The formula analyzer is not pictured in the screenshot, and B1 is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You have indexed one column and in the example return a number for the column to return in the indexed data. This results in an error.
I think you try to return a match of where two row conditions match. This is realized by:
`=INDEX($L$7:$L$44,MATCH(1,($A3=$I$7:$I$44)*(C2=$J$7:$J$44),0))`
Enter with `ctrl+shift+enter`

Comment: Thanks for your reply worked once i cntrl shift enter and created an array {}. Also found that =SUMIFS($L:$L,$J:$J,C$8,$I:$I,$A9) also worked. The advantage of SUMIF is i do not have concern myself with a fixed array

Comment: True. Index match returns the first match within the array. Sumifs returns the sum of all matches of the criteria.